# adding a row of items to already existing list *PYTHON*

Tags: python, list, input

I'M trying to get the input of the user to a new book to my already existing list but finding it to do this. Below is the code and list I've been trying to use but not finding any luck. If anyone could help it would be very much appreciate. btw the list is originally txt file but I import it into python and put it into a empty list, so it is now a list of lists

```
def print_summary4():
    NBooks = []
    for index in range(master_book_list):
        author = str(input('Name of Author you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(author)
        title = str(input('Name of book you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(title)
        form = str(input('Format of book: '))
        NBooks.append(form)
        pub = str(input('Name of publisher: '))
        NBooks.append(pub)
        cost = int(input('What is the cost of this book: '))
        NBooks.append(cost)
        stock = int(input('How many stock does this book have: '))
        NBooks.append(stock)
        genre = str(input('What genre is this: '))
        NBooks.append(genre)
    NBooks()
```

**list**

```
#Listing showing sample book details 
#AUTHOR, TITLE, FORMAT, PUBLISHER, COST?, STOCK, GENRE
P.G. Wodehouse, Right Ho Jeeves, hb, Penguin, 10.99, 5, fiction
A. Pais, Subtle is the Lord, pb, OUP, 12.99, 2, biography
A. Calaprice, The Quotable Einstein, pb, PUP, 7.99, 6, science
M. Faraday, The Chemical History of a Candle, pb, Cherokee, 5.99, 1, science
C. Smith, Energy and Empire, hb, CUP, 60, 1, science
J. Herschel, Popular Lectures, hb, CUP, 25, 1, science
C.S. Lewis, The Screwtape Letters, pb, Fount, 6.99, 16, religion
J.R.R. Tolkein, The Hobbit, pb, Harper Collins, 7.99, 12, fiction
C.S. Lewis, The Four Loves, pb, Fount, 6.99, 7, religion
E. Heisenberg, Inner Exile, hb, Birkhauser, 24.95, 1, biography
G.G. Stokes, Natural Theology, hb, Black, 30, 1, religion
```

Comment: this question is not clear... are you dealing with lists or files?

Comment: @adir-abargil sorry and im dealing with lists

Comment: still not clear, what you are showing in the expected output is not a ist

Answer (score 0):

From your list, I am guessing that it is a list of lists. Hence I would advice you to add all the user inputs into a fresh list and then append this list to the list of books, almost similar to what you did. Here's is the code:

```
def print_summary4():
    NBooks = []
    for index in range(len(master_book_list)):
        author = str(input('Name of Author you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(author)
        title = str(input('Name of book you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(title)
        form = str(input('Format of book: '))
        NBooks.append(form)
        pub = str(input('Name of publisher: '))
        NBooks.append(pub)
        cost = int(input('What is the cost of this book: '))
        NBooks.append(cost)
        stock = int(input('How many stock does this book have: '))
        NBooks.append(stock)
        genre = str(input('What genre is this: '))
        NBooks.append(genre)
        master_book_list.append(NBooks)
    NBooks
```

I am adding the `NBooks` to the `master_book_list` after each iteration.
Let me know if this sounds good.

Edit:
If you want to add only 1 book, you can remove the for loop like this:

```
def print_summary4():
        NBooks = []
        author = str(input('Name of Author you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(author)
        title = str(input('Name of book you wish to add: '))
        NBooks.append(title)
        form = str(input('Format of book: '))
        NBooks.append(form)
        pub = str(input('Name of publisher: '))
        NBooks.append(pub)
        cost = int(input('What is the cost of this book: '))
        NBooks.append(cost)
        stock = int(input('How many stock does this book have: '))
        NBooks.append(stock)
        genre = str(input('What genre is this: '))
        NBooks.append(genre)
        master_book_list.append(NBooks)
        NBooks
```

Comment: I have edited the code to include `len(master_book_list)`. Please check

Comment: it keeps asking me for more books to add i only wish to add one book to the fresh list is that possible?

Comment: Okay, in order to add only 1 book, you can remove the for loop. I have added an edit to  the code to give you an example.

Comment: i get this error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Okay, can you specify which line gives you this error?

Comment: oh sorry yea its the NBooks()

Comment: Okay, remove the braces from `Nbooks`. Or just `print(Nbooks)` would do it.